# Distinct static library compiled with -ffunction-sections flag

Tags: gcc, clang, static-libraries, elf, sections

How to distinct static library compiled with `-ffunction-sections` compiler flag?

I want to determine is some particular `.a` library can benefit from `-Wl,--gc-sections` flag.

If there is way to list all the section names, then I can apply `| wc -l` to it and infer, that there is too many sections and the library is likely compiled with mentioned flags.

`readelf -S` just prints archived `*.o` filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple take on this:

```
# Collect function sections
$ readelf -S tmp.o | sed -ne 's/.*\] \.text.\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\) .*/\1/p' | sort -u > fun_sec.lst

# Collect function symbols
$ nm tmp.o | grep ' T ' | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u > fun_sym.lst

# Compare
$ COMM=$(comm -12 fun_sym.lst fun_sec.lst | wc -l)
$ UNIQ=$(comm -3 fun_sym.lst fun_sec.lst | wc -l)
$ if test $COMM -gt $UNIQ; then echo "tmp.o was likely compiled with -ffunction-sections"; fi
```

Comment: For `*.a` it may be prepended with `pushd $( mktemp -d ) ; cp $( dirs +1 )/libmy.a . ; ar x libmy.a ; # ...` (starting from dir with `libmy.a` library of interest).

Comment: @Orient: I think you don't need anything special for `.a`, both `readelf` and `nm` by default inspect all objects inside of it. So just replace `tmp.o` with `libmy.a`.